# Mount directory when navigating to it

Tags: mount, mountpoint

Is it possible to mount a drive when a user attempts to navigate to it?

For instance, if I were to have /dev/sda8 mounted upon /mnt/shared/, could I only mount it when a process attempts to list the contents of the directory. Would this require a simple fstab flag or a complex daemon watching for a system call?

Sorry if this is a little brief, or irrelevant to the site, please point me in the right direction if I am.

Comment: If you were tying to do this with NFS, I'd be suggesting using the autofs (automonter) capability.

Answer (score 0):

yes setup automount

apt-get install autofs5

add the following to /etc/auto.master
/-      /etc/auto.misc --timeout=20

add the following to /etc/auto.misc
/mnt/shared -fstype=ext4 :/dev/sda8

run: service autofs restart

enjoy

Comment: Sorry for not including this in my answer: does this work for ntfs - substituting ext4 for ntfs or ntfs-3g?

Comment: i've never tried it but I can't see why it would make a difference.